# Firebase: use Localstorage to render when internet is disconnected

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

This is a function i created to check if the internet gets disconnected during the run time of my application.

```
 checkConnectionStatus () {
    firebase.database().ref().child('.info/connected').once('value').then((connectedSnap) => {
      if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
        console.log('connected')
        this.connectionStatus = true
      } else {
        console.log('disconnected')
        this.connectionStatus = false
      }
      return connectedSnap
    })
  }
```

I have used this function in another class like shown below, but the connection status is not updating properly.

```
async update () {
    let tempCollection = null
    await this.firebaseService.checkConnectionStatus()
    if (this.firebaseService.connectionStatus) {
      tempCollection = await this.firebaseService.getTodoListAsCollection()
    } else if (!this.firebaseService.connectionStatus) {
      tempCollection = this.localStorage.getTodoList()
    }
.///
}
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the problem. It sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you show a single piece of code that doesn't work the way you expect it to work?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, i have updated my post. Can you please check it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return anything from your `checkConnectionStatus` function. `async`/`await` requires a `Promise` to properly work. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function.

So something like this should get closer:

```
checkConnectionStatus () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    firebase.database().ref().child('.info/connected').once('value').then((connectedSnap) => {
      if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
        console.log('connected')
        this.connectionStatus = true
      } else {
        console.log('disconnected')
        this.connectionStatus = false
      }
      resolve();
    })
  }
```

A much simpler version could be:

```
checkConnectionStatus () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    firebase.database().ref().child('.info/connected').once('value').then((connectedSnap) => {
      resolve(connectedSnap.val())
    })
  }
}
```

Which you then use as:

```
let tempCollection = null
let connectionStatus = await this.firebaseService.checkConnectionStatus()
if (connectionStatus) {
  tempCollection = await this.firebaseService.getTodoListAsCollection()
} else if (!connectionStatus) {
  tempCollection = this.localStorage.getTodoList()
}
```

Or you can go without the helper function altogether, since `once()` already returns a promise:

```
let tempCollection = null
let snapshot = await firebase.database().ref().child('.info/connected').once('value')
let connectionStatus = snapshot.val()
if (connectionStatus) {
  tempCollection = await this.firebaseService.getTodoListAsCollection()
} else if (!connectionStatus) {
  tempCollection = this.localStorage.getTodoList()
}
```

Comment: Can we also use this approach with on() instead of once? As i would need the connectionstatus to be true when the internet is connected.